# Null Reference exception was unhandled by user code and item is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This working but all of a sudden it stopped working and was throwing null reference exception, when i checked in my basket record was inserted but the item is still null: the error is around `BasketItem item = basket.BasketItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.product_Id == product_Id);`

```
    using my_eCommerce.Contracts.Repositories;
    using my_eCommerce.Model;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web;

    namespace my_eCommerce.Services
    {
        public class BasketService
        {
            IRepositoryBase<Basket> baskets;
            public const string BasketSessionName = "eCommerceBasket";
            public BasketService(IRepositoryBase<Basket> baskets)
            {
                this.baskets = baskets;
            }
            private Basket CreateNewBasket(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                //create a new basket
                //
                //ffirst ceate a new cookie
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(BasketSessionName);
                // Now create a new Basket and set the creation date
                Basket basket = new Basket();

                //basket.BasketId = Guid.NewGuid(); //basket.BasketId = Guid.NewGuid() is supposed to come after date;
                basket.Basket_Id = Guid.NewGuid();

                basket.date = DateTime.Now;

                baskets.Insert(basket);
                baskets.Commit();

                //Add basketId to a cookie
                cookie.Value = basket.Basket_Id.ToString();
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                return basket;
            }
            public bool AddToBasket(HttpContextBase httpContext, int product_Id, int quantity)
            {
                bool succcess = true;
                Basket basket = GetBasket(httpContext);
                //BasketItem item = basket.BasketItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.product_Id == product_Id);
                BasketItem item = basket.BasketItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.product_Id == product_Id);
                if (item == null)
                {
                    item = new BasketItem()
                    {
                        Basket_Id = basket.Basket_Id,
                        product_Id = product_Id,
                        Quantity = quantity
                    };
                    basket.BasketItems.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Quantity = item.Quantity + quantity;
                }
                baskets.Commit();

                return succcess;
            }
            public Basket GetBasket(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies.Get(BasketSessionName);
                Basket basket;
                Guid basket_Id;

                if (cookie != null)
                {
                    if (Guid.TryParse(cookie.Value, out basket_Id))
                    {
                        basket = baskets.GetById(basket_Id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        basket = CreateNewBasket(httpContext);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    basket = CreateNewBasket(httpContext);
                }
                return basket;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please debug your code and check which object is `null`. Is it `basket` or `basket.BasketItems`?

Comment: Basket.basketitem is null but basket is not null

Answer (score 0):

Your `basket` or `basket.BasketItems` objects could be null in some situations. You should put `Null` check for this object the way you have done for the `item` object. Try to rewrite the code in the following way:

```
...
BasketItem item = null;
Basket basket = GetBasket(httpContext);
if(basket != null && basket.BasketItems != null)
{
   item = basket.BasketItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.product_Id == product_Id);
}

if (item == null)
{
...
```

Comment: I still get item error at basket.BasketItems.Add(item); but in the trace there was product_Id, basketItem_id is null and basket_id is not null except for item(BasketItem_Id)

Comment: The basket get created but it does not add items (Product_id, Basket_Id, quantity to BasketItem) and the BasketItem_Id is null and it throws the error at basket.BasketItems.Add(item);

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Null-conditional operators ?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

You can use it like below and it will not throw exception but it will return

- `null` if `basket` is `null`.
- `null` if `basket.BasketItems` is `null`.
- Or FirstOrDefault() value from `basket.BasketItems`

---

```
BasketItem item = basket?.BasketItems?.FirstOrDefault(i => i.product_Id == product_Id);
```